# How to set the default shell when chsh is not present

Tags: shell, zsh, synology

I've a Synology DS412+ NAS box running Busybox, which has a default shell of `ash`. Previously, `ipkg install optware-devel` was run and it installed `bash` and set it as the default shell. Running `ipkg install zsh` has installed `zsh` but not set it as the default shell. `chsh` is not present (Busybox assumes a cut down system and only `ash` will be used), so how do I set the default shell?

I'd be very grateful for any help or insight .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change the login shell by editing `/etc/passwd`. Each line is a list of colon-separated values, the last of which is the login shell:

```
user:x:1000:1000:User:/home/user:/usr/bin/zsh
```

If `/etc/shells` exists, you should add zsh (full path) to it, else some services may not work for your user.

*Note:*

I'd suggest against changing the login shell for root (or any user you need for administrative purposes) if `zsh` is installed on one of the disks. You may want to still have root access without installed disks.

You always could start `zsh` automatically from ash's user configuration. Something like that

```
[ -x /usr/bin/zsh ] && exec /usr/bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method From this post on the Synoloogy forum:

https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/150323

In your editor of choice (e.g. nano), add the following lines to:
~/.profile

export SHELL=/bin/bash
exec /bin/bash

where /bin/bash is the path to your chosen shell